# Js function not defined

Tags: javascript

I was working on a simple show and hide function and it kept telling me that it's not defined.

Here's the HTML:

```
<address>
<a id="windows" href="#" onclick="toggle();">
<img src="imges/c980e3f5-badf-432a-ae6c-9e5341d13462.png" alt="" />
</a>
</address>
         <p class="right_page">
           this is sample of the book container<br/>
           thats suppose to read from ajax
            </p>
```

and here the function

```
    <script type="text/javasript">
function toggle() 
{
    var ele = document.getElementById("right_page");
    var text = document.getElementById("windows");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
} 

</script>
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're getting (i.e. what exactly is not defined).

Comment: did you define the function in the head of the document?

Comment: Try to debug with http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: thats the error toggle is not defined

Comment: i define the function on the html body

Comment: where is the id "right_page" in code, you have only class named right_page

Answer (score 2):

I think it is due to a typo in your `script` tag. Change `type="text/javasript"` to `type="text/javascript"` (missing the `c`).

### Update

Your image is being removed from the DOM due to you setting the innerHtml to a string. This overwrites the image which is part of the innerHtml.

The first time that you run `toggle()` there is not an inline style for `display` so `ele.style.display` will be an empty string. This means that it will drop into the logic for showing the paragraph. On subsequent calls the property will have a value so it should behave as you expect.

Comment: oops yeah its work but work very strange its replace the link background image with hide and show word and so its hide the image of the link not the div i want it to hide

Comment: @aly1984: Does the `div` also have the ID `windows`? IDs have to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong here:

1. Did you paste this in directly from your code? If so, your `<script type...` line contains a typo (should be "javas**c**ript")
2. You can't use `getElementById()` for `right_page` as it stands, because `right_page` is only defined as a class in your mark-up.

Comment: You need to sort the rest of your code out too. For example, setting `innerHTML` on `windows` means that your image is effectively removed from the page and replaced with some text.

Answer (score 0):

**First you missed the C** change `type="text/javascript"`, second the `right_pae` is not a `ID`,
can't use `document.getElementById` because there are something wrong with your function, so it tells you the function is undefined